# continue loop within a function, if statement, function, and if statement (javascript)

Tags: node.js, nested, label, continue

I'm in a complicated situation in Node.js:

```
HOME: WHILE (TRUE):
    AWAIT INQUIRER.PROMPT(...)
    .THEN(FUNCTION(...):
        IF ...
        ELIF:
            AWAIT INQUIRER.PROMPT(...)
            .THEN(FUNCTION(...):
                IF:
                    CONTINUE HOME // ?!
                ENDIF
            END
        ENDIF
     END
END
```

Using simple continue didn't work, or continue with label. goto with label didn't work.